# Keeping specific legend position constant in plotly for stack bar chart

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have plotted a stacked bar chart, when i click on the legend the selected one will go down to bottom. Instead i want it to stay in the same position. Kindly advice.

For eg., in the mentioned code, if double click on legend virginica it will go down to the bottom though its at the top. I want to view it in the same position.

Kindly help

```
import plotly.express as px 
  
df = px.data.iris() 
  
fig = px.bar(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", 
            hover_data=['petal_width'], barmode = 'stack') 
  
fig.show()
```

Comment: What version of Plotly are you using? I am not noticing this problem actually- it looks like the order of the species stays the same in the legend, and for the stacked bars (Virginica on top, followed by versicolor, then setosa on the bottom).

Comment: Hi @DerekO Thanks, but i want to keep it in the same position. basically, i want to highlight the virginica alone fixed(it should not go to bottom when i double click).